# Can I change NSScreen visibleframe?

Tags: cocoa, screen, macos

I trying to create a toolbar that docks on the top of the screen below the OS X menu bar.

I would like no other application's to be able to overlap my application when they are maximized.  I can get the visible frame dimensions using NSScreen's visibleframe method, but can I adjust the visibleframe to omit the size and position of my application?

Comment: What window level have you assigned to your window(s)?

Comment: I assigned my window level as: NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel.  This got my window to be on top of other windows, but when I maximize the other windows they go underneath my window, I would like them to stop at the bottom of my window and not go underneath my application.  Like how the dock stops windows from going over it when maximized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that no, you can't. I think that the only way to change the screen's `visibleRect` would be to inject code into AppKit and swizzle the method.

Even then, it might not do what you want because that method might not be what Apple uses to determine the "safe area" for windows and almost certainly would not work with Carbon apps.

Nothing you do with window levels will change this.

What you *could* do is use the Accessibility framework to reposition windows if you detect that their frames have changed such that they overlap your toolbar window. Unfortunately, I think you might need use polling for this.

Comment: Thanks at least I know now, and knowing is half the battle

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your window's level to `NSDockWindowLevel`.

This may not work, depending on whether the system subtracts all windows on that level or only ever the Dock's window, but it's worth a try.

Comment: This did the same thing as NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel.  Maybe it is not possible to create toolbars or taskbars for the Mac that can alter the workarea of the OS, I haven't seen one before.